# Ejecutar acción al presionar enter

Tags: jsf

Tengo un formulario que tiene solamente dos elementos, un `inputText` y un`commandLink`, lo que quiero es que al presionar enter dentro del `inputText` se ejecute el `action` del `commandLink`, según yo deberia de hacerlo automaticamente, pero no es así.

Esté es mi código:

```
<h:form>
            <div class="container">

                <div style="float: left; width: 600px;">
                    <p:inputText placeholder="Búsqueda de guía"
                                 value="#{busquedaCtrl.noGuia}"/>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; width: 150px;">
                    <p:commandLink class="boton" value="Buscar"
                                   action="#{busquedaCtrl.buscar}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolverlo agregé un `remoteCommand` y lo invoque al detectar con js que se presionó la tecla enter y quedó de la siguiente forma :

```
                <div style="float: left; width: 600px;">
                    <p:inputText placeholder="Búsqueda de guía"
                                 value="#{busquedaCtrl.noGuia}"
                                 onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                                             test();
                                             return false;
                                         }"/>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; width: 150px;">
                    <p:commandLink class="boton" value="Buscar"
                                   action="#{busquedaCtrl.buscar}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes optar por un evento ajax o un remote command:

No lo probe pero debería funcionar:

```
<p:inputText id="inputEnter"  placeholder="Búsqueda de guía"
             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false; }" 
            value="#{busquedaCtrl.noGuia}">
       <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.save}" update="messages"/>
   </p:inputText
```